# watir-webdriver cookie jar saving and loading

Tags: serialization, cookies, watir, watir-webdriver

I'm surprised there didn't seem to be much discussion on this.

in [Mechanize](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/) I can easily read an entire cookie jar from the browser, store it to a file, and load it in to a later session/run before loading that website's pages again.

How can one do the same with **watir-webdriver**?

UPDATE

Now with [0.5.2](http://watirwebdriver.com/cookies/)  I do see new methods `browser.cookies.to_hash`
which would turn this question into "How to implement **.from_hash** or similar loader using eg. `.clear` and `.add`?"

However I'd be especially keen on loading and saving all cookies using previous versions (0.4.1) which my servers are likely to be stuck with for a while.  Via the Selenium driver maybe?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```rb
browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
browser.goto 'http://google.com'
# save cookies
saved_cookies = browser.cookies.to_a
# clear and get new cookies
browser.cookies.clear
browser.goto 'http://google.com'
# set new cookies
browser.cookies.clear
saved_cookies.each do |saved_cookie|
  browser.cookies.add(saved_cookie[:name], saved_cookie[:value])
end
```

Comment: Almost. Thanks! Saving & reloading array from plaintext file become somewhat problematic, so I used YAML. Posting full solution below

Answer (score 4):

Applying [pOdeje](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9239869/1069375)'s loop to repopulate the cookie jar, here's a solution that includes storing the cookies into a file, readable in a later Ruby run.  A straight `File.open` write and read of the array had some issues I didn't wish to work around (parsing?), but **YAML object serialization** already bundled in Ruby was well suited to the task.

```
require 'yaml'

# Save/serialize cookies 
# File.open("ST.cookies.txt", 'w').write $browser.cookies.to_a.to_s 
File.open("ST.cookies.yaml", 'w').write YAML::dump($browser.cookies.to_a)


# Load/deserialize cookies
# $cookies = File.open("ST.cookies.txt", 'r').to_a # returns 1-elem array of single long line, not indiv elements
$cookies = YAML::load(File.open("ST.cookies.yaml", 'r'))
$browser.cookies.clear
$cookies.each do |saved_cookie|
  $browser.cookies.add saved_cookie[:name], 
      saved_cookie[:value],
      :domain => saved_cookie[:domain], 
      :expires => saved_cookie[:expires], 
      :path => saved_cookie[:path], 
      :secure => saved_cookie[:secure]
    end
```

Still on the lookout for a pre `watir-webdriver 0.5.x` method, though.

**CAVEAT**

Not thoroughly tested yet but it seems I have to *first* load the URL to which the cookies apply, *then* load in my cookie jar using the above method, and *finally* load that URL into `$browser` object **a second time**.  This is only a minor inconvenience and time cost for my case in which I'm staying within the same domain throughout my web session, but I can see this turning into a real thorn for cookie jars affecting several unrelated sites (as had indeed been an expectation for my old programs using other languages & libraries like Mechanize).  Curl and Wget and generally other tools I've used for SOAP interfacing always let me control my POST/session/cookie environments prior to site loading. Just a thought.

Comment: Amended to include cookie's :domain :expires :path and :secure as well...possibly the reason my jar seemed ignored and I still had to create a whole new session every time!

Comment: good stuff.   does make me wonder how many folks would need or make use of methods such as .save_cookies and .load_cookies if they were to be added

Comment: I've been using those two cookie jar functions in other web-driving libraries for years--usually to extend session lifetime or manipulate data offsite--and would positively love to see them in the Watir specs too. But I just ran into another problem I feel I need to warn about; commenting above.

Comment: FYI watir-webdriver now implements `Cookie#save` and `Cookie#load` which saves/loads cookies to/form YAML file